# libusb_init() returns -99

Tags: linux, kernel

I have successfully built both `libfreenect` (driver for Xbox Kinect) and `libusb` (which is a dependency).

However, if I try to open the Kinect using the `freenect_init(...)` function, it returns `-99`.

I tracked down the error to the funtion `libusb_init(...)` which is returning this error, `LIBUSB_ERROR_OTHER`.

As I use a minified custom kernel configuration (version: 2.6.37) I think I missed to enable an important config option.
Kernel config is available [on pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/jSPMZed2).

The Kinect gets successfully recognized (reported in dmesg including correct product/vendor information).

Does anyone has an idea how to get rid of this error?

**UPDATE:**
After setting the `LIBUSB_DEBUG` environment variable to `3` I got the following message:
`[op_init] could not find usbfs`

Comment: Did you try with a "normal" kernel? If it works there, something is wrong with your config, and you need to find out what.

Comment: Unfortunately there isnt enough space available to have a much bigger kernel.

Comment: Paste your config to pastebin, otherwise there is little to talk about...

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: Thanks, I added the link to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`libusb` requires that the VFS `usbfs` is mounted. After adding the following line to `/etc/fstab` the problem was solved:

```
usbfs   /proc/bus/usb   usbfs   defaults   0   0
```